# Specific binomial probabilities?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been working out the probability of some events, using $$\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

but I'd like to get more complex with my calculations.
The trials can be simplified as coin flips, but an unfair coin. Say $$Tails =p$$ $$Heads = 1-p$$ 
Now rather than find the probability of 5 coins being flipped resulting in 3 Heads etc (I have done this) I'd like to examine the probability of specific outcomes.
For example, 5 different coins are flipped together, 32 possible outcomes, 23 of those outcomes are 'winning', and 9 are not.

5H is a win (1 way)
4H is a win (5 ways, all 5 win)
3H is a win(10 ways, all 10 win)
2H: only a specific 6 of the 10 possible ways wins
1H: only 1 of the 5 ways will win (getting a head on a specific coin only will win)
0H is a loss (1 way)

I'm hoping someone can help me with a nice general mathematical process so I can work out probabilities with different numbers of coins and different winning conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add up the probabilities of each winning configuration. For instance, the probability of winning with a $3H$ configuration is $\binom{5}{2}p^2(1-p)^3=10p^2(1-p)^3$. To deal with the, say, $2H$ configurations where only $6$ of them win, you would simply use a coefficient of $6$ instead of $\binom{5}{3}$; so you'd have $6 p^3(1-p)^2$ as the probability of winning with a $2H$ configuration.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I hadn't thought of using $k = not Heads$ and good to know they can all be added up!